# 暗号化された情報の全文検索方法

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Evernoteのようなツールを作成しています。Evernoteのように秘密にすべき情報を扱う場合、暗号化してデータベースに保存する必要があると思うのですが、暗号化した情報を全文検索エンジンで処理する方法が見つかりません、暗号化した情報を全文検索するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか?（手がかりになるキーワードだけでも教えていただけると嬉しいです）

Comment: キーワードとして、秘密計算(Secure Computation), 検索可能暗号(Searchable Encryption), 準同型暗号(Homomorphic Encryption)を挙げておきます。

Comment: 「データベース」とはいわゆるRDBMSのことを意味していますか？

Comment: 「データベース」は、データを保存する場所という意味で使っています！RDBMSでもKVSでも、そこに暗号化して保存してしまうと保存したデータを全文検索エンジンで使用することができないという悩みですが、metropolis さんがコメントしていただいているように、検索可能暗号など暗号化した後も検索で使用する方法はあるんですね！（結構、難しいですね。。。）